# Display an int variable in a MessageBox

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on an old app written in Visual C++ 6.0.  I am trying to display an `int` variable in a `MessageBox` for debugging reasons. Here is my code, I thought this would be a simple process, but I am just learning C++.  The two lines that are commented I have tried as well with similar errors.  Below is the error I am getting.

```
int index1 = 1;
char test1 = index1;
// char var1[] = index1;
// char *varGo1 = index1;
MessageBox(NULL, test1, "testx", MB_OK);
```

> error C2664: 'MessageBoxA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char' to 'const char *'

Answer (score 9):

Why bother with C-style strings if you tagged C++?

Although [Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) provided [MFC solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20433728/1607442) (which is perfectly valid), here is a Standard C++ one:

```
int index1 = 1;
std::string test1 = std::to_string(index1);
MessageBoxA(NULL, test1.c_str(), "testx", MB_OK);
```

References:

- [std::to_string()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string);
- [Arrays are evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html)

Use [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) for more sophisticated formatting.

Answer (score 4):

```
CString str1;
str1.Format(_T("%d"), index1);
MessageBox(NULL, str1, "testx", MB_OK);
```

CString's `Format` works just like `printf` to populate the string with the parameter list.

Answer (score 4):

```
int index1 = 1;
char buf[10];
itoa(index1,buf,10);
MessageBox(NULL,buf,"Caption",MB_OK);
```

Can try this

Comment: The return value from GetDlgItemInt() is **UINT** so it should be **_ultoa** instead of **itoa**.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of `MessageBox` needs to be a pointer to a *string* of `char`s, terminated with NULL. Passing a `char` will not work.

But, learning to use a debugger is an integral part to learning a language. Why not build a debug build and set a breakpoint on `char test1 = index1;` instead? You do that by pressing F9 when the cursor is on that line.

Comment: +100 for "learning to use a debugger is an integral part to learning a language". Unfortunately, code in question doesn't compiles, so nothing to debug :(

Comment: Unfortunately 'twas balanced by -100 ;-)

Comment: Yeah, looks like someone really doesn't like debugging =)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I prefer to use a manipulator for this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using std::ostringstream;
using std::ostream;

ostream &msg_box(ostream &s) {
    ostringstream &os = dynamic_cast<ostringstream &>(s);

    MessageBox(NULL, os.str().c_str(), "testx", MB_OK);
    return s;
}

int main() { 
    ostringstream msg;
    msg << "The number is: " << 10 << msg_box;
    return 0;
}
```

This maintains (mostly) the same interface nearly everybody's already accustomed to with `iostream`s, avoids the type-unsafe `CString::Format`, and avoids having several lines of distraction everywhere you're going to display a little information for debugging. The other obvious good point is that if you've overloaded `operator<<` for your own type, that overload will work with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to your error, you should declare a const pointer on the second parameter.
Like this,

```
const char * test1= new char();
```

or use

```
std::string test1= "";
MessageBox(NULL, test1.c_str(), "testx", MB_OK);
```

Also using just "Text" will work.

Comment: I don't think the goal is to display an empty string.

Comment: Yea, he need to display `int`

Comment: Got it, so he could use std::to_string(Int), but he will still need to use the correct parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pure **C** solution using ***sprintf*** method to store all input in buffer and passing that buffer to **MessageBox**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    int intVal = 50;
    float fltVal = 5.5;
    char *str = "Test String";
    char buf[1024] = {'\0'};//buffer to store formatted input.

    //convert formatted input into buffer.
    sprintf(buf,"Int value : %d\nFloat value : %f\nString : %s\n",intVal,fltVal,str);

    //display whole buffer.
    MessageBox(NULL,buf,"INFO",MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    return 0;
}
```